# Regular Expression issue matching string pattern "A-Za-z-A-Za-z_"

Tags: c#, xml, regex, linq-to-xml, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a regular expression to match a form of string :

```
"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]_[match all chars]"
```

The string I want to match must be of this form, including the hyphen and underscore. So far I have :

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+(-[A-Za-z]+)+*$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

I am not sure how to add in the underscore character so that this is matched.

This element is an XML element I wish to match; I would also like to retrieve the contents of this element. How could I do this ?

```
var newVar = from e in doc.Descendants("DocumentElement").Descendants() 
                         where regEx.IsMatch(e.Name.LocalName) 
                        select e;
```

Comment: Please give a sample of the input text, and the matches you want to find. This is too vague. Regex can do a great job of finding matches if there's enough information. Is it a single expression that has to match the regex? Is it a whole text where you need to find matches? Those are very different things. (I really don't understand how other people has been able to give an answer without this info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use

```
@"^[A-Za-z]{2}-[A-Za-z]{2}_.*$"
```

Explanation:

- `^` beginning of the line
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` exactly 2 characters must be a-zA-Z
- `-` the dash
- `_` the underscore
- `.*` any character
- `$` end of the line

EDIT:

See also [Regex docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your example pattern uses the + modifier which is "more than 1", not 2. It will match more than you think.

```cs
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]{2}-[A-Za-z]{2}_.*$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Or just set the case insensitive option too with:

```cs
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}_.*$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Regex you want is:

```
new Regex(@"^[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z][A-Z]_", RegexOptions.CaseInsensitive);
```

This should capture:
`^[A-Z][A-Z]` two alpha characters at the start
`-` the literal hyphen character
`[A-Z][A-Z]` two more alpha characters
`_` the literal underscore character

You don't say you want to capture the whole name of this xml tag, so you don't need to capture the `.*$` "any other characters till the end of string" part.

Answer (score 1):

See this regex.

Tested on nregex.com

```
^[A-Za-z]+(-[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]{2})$
```

Key things here:-

- Last part of string qualified to 2 characters ( replace this with + if you don't care about 2 characters exactly).

This also performs the capture.

Comment: You don't need to escape hyphens (except in a character class, but only when they are not at the start or the end of the class).